# Returning an open data reader from a WCF Service

Tags: wcf, ado.net

Is it possible to return a data reader from a WCF Service api to a client which is running on a different machine. The serialization mechanism being used is NetDataContractSerializer. The data reader is being sent to the client to read chunks of binary data from the database. The data reader has a method GetBytes() which supports chunking.

Is above thing possible. Is anything wrong with this approach. Are there any alternatives to support chunking?

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I was not aware of it. Shall I accept the answers even if they are not to the expectation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does not make sense to return an open datareader from a WCF service. Please read the responses in [this msdn forum thread](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wcf/thread/75ed1144-be40-4089-83ad-ab50a889ffef).

Comment: Since content on msft pages is sometimes removed here is the slightly shortened answer from dwight goins: since the datareader is not serializable you can't send and receive DataReaders as input and output parameters, unless you wrap it inside a Serializable class, or use the Serialization options discussed here:

http://msdn2.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731073.aspx

Streaming wise, you could always use the streaming binding options available to stream data from the DataReader in and out of the Service if you implement the IDataReader interfaces and apply the stream coding respectively.